# In what situations does parameterizing a query NOT prevent SQL Injection?

Tags: sql-injection

While this isn't terribly common, I know that SQL Injection is still possible with a parameterized query, if you are calling a stored procedure that uses a parameter to construct and execute dynamic SQL.

I'm curious if there are any other edge case scenarios where SQL Injection is still possible even if you are using parameterized queries?  Is dynamic SQL the only catch?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only one that immediately comes to mind is second order injection where a value such as `123' or 1=1 --` is stored in a table which is later retrieved and then used unfiltered in a query. It does usually require the code to not parameterize data retrieved from the database which is not that uncommon as developers often consider this a "trusted" source.

Comment: Good answer.  It's also possible to insert malicious data that performs other forms of injection, such as XPATH or XSS.

Comment: [SQL injection is SQL injection, no matter where the injected data came from.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22729097/53114)

Comment: I never said it wasn't SQL injection?

Comment: I meant, there is no need to differentiate where the data came from because it simply doesn’t matter. Thus there is no need to differentiate between ‘first order’, ‘second order’, or ‘nth order’ injections because everything is just an injection. And parameterization can protect against it.

Comment: It matters when you have to patch the vulnerability. Knowing that its second order means you look at places where database values are used as opposed to where the values gets accepted from the user.

Comment: @Gumbo, it absolutely matters when I am specifically asking how the sql injection would take place.

Comment: @AbeMiessler In that case the answer would be: you’re using a value without ensuring it’s getting interpreted as intended. Quoting [CWE-89](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/89.html): “The software constructs all or part of an SQL command using externally-influenced input […], but it does not neutralize or incorrectly neutralizes special elements that could modify the intended SQL command […].” Just make sure that *every value* gets passed as parameter, no matter if it’s from the user’s request, from a previous query, from a file, or even from a variable with a (currently) static value.

Comment: That seems like a very high level explanation of SQL Injection, but I'm asking specifically about how attacks would take place (like my dynamic SQL example).  I touched on this in my comment on your answer - but parameterizing wouldn't fix the dynamic SQL vulnerability would it?  I do agree that it would take care of second/Nth order attacks

Answer (score -1):

Using prepared statements with parameters only ensures that the given parameters are securely passed to the DBMS as intended. Such a prepared statement definitely won’t be injectable.

However, when the prepared statement itself utilizes functionalities like stored procedures that contain injection flaws themselves, you’re obviously still vulnerable. But it’s not the prepared statement that’s vulnerable but the stored procedure (which could probably also use prepared statements as mitigation).

Comment: -1, I feel like you are repeating what I said in my original question and also not answering what I asked.  This might be better off as a comment.  I do agree that the stored proc is what is vulnerable, but I don't think that using a prepared statement would protect against the dynamic sql scenario I described would it?

Comment: @AbeMiessler Prepared statements with parameterization is the solution to SQL injections, even when you’re building the query dynamically. Yes, it gets more complicated. But there are techniques like [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) that  have already solved this problem of building SQL statements dynamically. Use them, don’t build your own.

Comment: Chat? http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18839/sql-injection